# Как создать bat файл для косольного приложения c#?

Tags: c#, bat, .net-core

При запуске dotnet run run.bat должны осуществиться компиляция и запуск приложения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его сделать. Нагуглить не смог.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Comment: Почитал, опять погуглил, все равно не  получается. Батника нет.  Можно, пожалуйста, поподробнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаешь текстовый файл в любом месте файловой системы, в нем пишешь следующую строчку

```
start "" "ссылка в файловой системе на компилируемое приложение"
```

Например:

```
start "" "C:\Users\vorob\source\repos\glova\glova.cs"
```

Закрываешь файл, расширение ставишь .bat